# Throwing an exception from a ServletContextListener

Tags: java, servlets

I want to throw a ServletContext exception from a method in a class which implements `ServletContextLister`.

Here is my implementation which is failing:

```
public class  Initializer implements ServletContextListener {

    private void checkEncryptedFile() throws ServletException {

    FileReader fr;
    try {
        fr = new FileReader("TestFile");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String str = br.readLine();
        if(!str.equals("aasditya")){
        throw new ServletException();
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ServletException se){
        throw new ServletException("kiasku " + se.getMessage(), se);

    }
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest any alternate methods. Please guide me on this.
Thanks

Comment: How is it failing. If you add logging what is the execution path?

Comment: And more importantly, why do you want to throw this exception, and what do you expect to happen once you throw it? The context listener isn't meant to be a point of control; put that it your servlet initialization instead.

Answer (score 2):

When the interface method is throwing an exception too, you should remove the catch blocks without

```
try {
                //....

    }
    catch(IOException e){
            throw new ServletException("kiasku " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

And than your exception handling should work.

**EDIT:**

Do you have implemented the interface methods of [ServletContextListener](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) correctly? They are not in your code example. But they have to be in the class.

As far as i see, the interfae methods are not throwing any type of exceptions. When you realy want to BREAK the listener notification, you have to throw a RuntimeException.

**EDIT2:**

I would also change

```
if(!str.equals("aasditya")){
throw new ServletException();
}
```

to

```
if(!"aasditya".equals(str)){
throw new ServletException();
}
```

Comment: "Do you have implemented the interface methods of ServletContextListener correctly? They are not in your code example. But they have to be in the class." - Yes I have added them .I'm calling the above method from in interface-method.